# Making a function that can accept different types of templated class inputs

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

I have an application where I need to reduce the memory usage of my matrix classes.  Many of my matrices are symmetric, and so should only require *N(N+1)/2* memory instead of *N<sup>2</sup>*.  I can't simply have a `MatrixSym` class that derives from my `Matrix` class because a child class always uses more memory than the base class.  I've defined a `MatrixAbstract` class from which both classes inherit, however I am having trouble getting a matrix multiplication function to work on both of them.

## My question

How can I define a `C = multiply(A,B)` function that accepts either a `Matrix` or `MatrixSym` object for any input/output?  My minimal working example is not so minimal, because it contains four definitions of `multiply` that all use the same code and should be combined into one.

### Requirements

- Static allocation only
- Must use `std::array` for matrix elements
- Minimal repeated code: I have many matrix operations and the only thing different about `MatrixSym` is the way it stores and accesses elements from the underlying `matVals` array.

```
#include <array> 
#include <iostream> 

template<unsigned int ROWS, unsigned int COLS, unsigned int NUMEL>
class MatrixAbstract
{
private:
    static constexpr unsigned int numel = NUMEL; 
    std::array<double, NUMEL> matVals;   // The array of matrix elements
public:
    MatrixSuperclass(){}
    virtual unsigned int index_from_rc(const unsigned int& row, const unsigned int& col) const = 0;
    // get the value at a given row and column
    double get_value(const int& row, const int& col) const
    {
        return this->matVals[this->index_from_rc(row,col)];
    }
    // set the value, given the row and column
    void set_value(const int& row, const int& col, double value)
    {
        this->matVals[this->index_from_rc(row,col)] = value;
    }

};

template<unsigned int ROWS, unsigned int COLS, unsigned int NUMEL = ROWS*COLS>
class Matrix : public MatrixSuperclass<ROWS, COLS, NUMEL>
{
public:
    Matrix(){}
    // get the linear index in matVals corresponding to a row,column input
    unsigned int index_from_rc(const unsigned int& row, const unsigned int& col) const {
        return row*COLS + col; 
    }
};

template<unsigned int ROWS, unsigned int COLS = ROWS, unsigned int NUMEL = ROWS*(ROWS+1)/2> 
class MatrixSym : public MatrixSuperclass<ROWS, COLS, NUMEL>
{
public:
    MatrixSym(){}
    // get the linear index in matVals corresponding to a row,column input (Symmetric matrix)
    unsigned int index_from_rc(const unsigned int& row, const unsigned int& col) const {
        unsigned int z;
        return ( ( z = ( row < col ? col : row ) ) * ( z + 1 ) >> 1 ) + ( col < row ? col : row ) ;
    }
};

// THE FOLLOWING FOUR FUNCTIONS ALL USE THE EXACT SAME CODE, ONLY INPUT/OUTPUT TYPES CHANGE

// Multiply a Matrix and Matrix and output a Matrix
template<unsigned int ROWS, unsigned int COLS, unsigned int INNER>
Matrix<ROWS,COLS> multiply (Matrix<ROWS,INNER>& inMatrix1, Matrix<INNER,COLS>& inMatrix2) {
    Matrix<ROWS,COLS> outMatrix;
    for (unsigned int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
        for (unsigned int c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
            double val = 0.0;
            for (unsigned int rc = 0; rc < INNER; rc++) {
                val += inMatrix1.get_value(r,rc)*inMatrix2.get_value(rc,c);
            }
            outMatrix.set_value(r,c,val);
        }
    }
    return outMatrix;
}

// Multiply a Matrix and MatrixSym and output a Matrix
template<unsigned int ROWS, unsigned int COLS, unsigned int INNER>
Matrix<ROWS,COLS> multiply (Matrix<ROWS,INNER>& inMatrix1, MatrixSym<INNER,COLS>& inMatrix2) {
    Matrix<ROWS,COLS> outMatrix;
    for (unsigned int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
        for (unsigned int c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
            double val = 0.0;
            for (unsigned int rc = 0; rc < INNER; rc++) {
                val += inMatrix1.get_value(r,rc)*inMatrix2.get_value(rc,c);
            }
            outMatrix.set_value(r,c,val);
        }
    }
    return outMatrix;
}

// Multiply a MatrixSym and Matrix and output a Matrix
template<unsigned int ROWS, unsigned int COLS, unsigned int INNER>
Matrix<ROWS,COLS> multiply (MatrixSym<ROWS,INNER>& inMatrix1, Matrix<INNER,COLS>& inMatrix2) {
    //MatrixSym<ROWS,COLS> outMatrixSym;
    Matrix<ROWS,COLS> outMatrix;
    for (unsigned int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
        for (unsigned int c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
            double val = 0.0;
            for (unsigned int rc = 0; rc < INNER; rc++) {
                val += inMatrix1.get_value(r,rc)*inMatrix2.get_value(rc,c);
            }
            outMatrix.set_value(r,c,val);
        }
    }
    return outMatrix;
}

// Multiply a MatrixSym and MatrixSym and output a MatrixSym
template<unsigned int ROWS, unsigned int COLS, unsigned int INNER>
MatrixSym<ROWS,COLS> multiply (MatrixSym<ROWS,INNER>& inMatrix1, MatrixSym<INNER,COLS>& inMatrix2) {
    //MatrixSym<ROWS,COLS> outMatrixSym;
    MatrixSym<ROWS,COLS> outMatrix;
    for (unsigned int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
        for (unsigned int c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
            double val = 0.0;
            for (unsigned int rc = 0; rc < INNER; rc++) {
                val += inMatrix1.get_value(r,rc)*inMatrix2.get_value(rc,c);
            }
            outMatrix.set_value(r,c,val);
        }
    }
    return outMatrix;
}

int main()
{
    Matrix<3,3> A;
    MatrixSym<3> S;
    Matrix<3,3> AtimesA = multiply(A,A);
    Matrix<3,3> AtimesS = multiply(A,S);
    Matrix<3,3> StimesA = multiply(S,A);
    MatrixSym<3> StimesS = multiply(S,S);
    
    // Make sure that symmetric matrix S is indeed smaller than A
    std::cout << "sizeof(A)/sizeof(double) = " << sizeof(A)/sizeof(double) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(S)/sizeof(double) = " << sizeof(S)/sizeof(double) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
sizeof(A)/sizeof(double) = 9
sizeof(S)/sizeof(double) = 15
```

## What I've tried

- If I try to make the function use `MatrixAbstract` as arguments I need to play around with the template parameters, since I can't have `NUMEL` as a template parameter.  Further, I can't instantiate a `MatrixAbstract` for the return value.
- I can't figure out how to template the function for either `Matrix` or `MatrixSym`.  My hunch is that this is the way to solve it, but I don't understand how to template the function for a templated class input, but with still being able to use `ROWS` and `COLS` as template arguments.

```
template<class InMatrix1Type, class InMatrix2Type, class OutMatrixType, unsigned int ROWS, unsigned int COLS, unsigned int INNER>
OutMatrixType<ROWS,COLS> multiply (InMatrix1Type<ROWS,INNER>& inMatrix1, InMatrix2Type<INNER,COLS>& inMatrix2)
```

gives me a compiler error starting with

```
error: ‘OutMatrixType’ is not a template
 OutMatrixType<ROWS,COLS> multiply (InMatrix1Type<ROWS,INNER>& inMatrix1, InMatrix2Type<INNER,COLS>& inMatrix2)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Are you using partial template specialization - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_template_specialization ?

Comment: Inheritance is the wrong tool here. Write your `multiply` function as a template that takes two type arguments, one for each matrix. Write a "normal" `Matrix` class, that provides (if I'm reading your code right with a quick skim) `get_value(unsigned, unsigned)` that returns a reference to the value at those indices. Write a second `SymmetricMatrix` class that provides `get_value(unsigned, unsigned)` that returns a reference to the value at those indices. `multiply` doesn't care whether the value it gets comes from a full matrix or from a symmetric (smaller) matrix.

Comment: Unless you are doing it for learning purposes, consider using an existing matrix library.

Comment: @PeteBecker, `Matrix` and `SymmetricMatrix` are almost identical, with the exception of the way they store data.  Isn't inheritance the best method for situations like these?  There are a bunch of other member functions and attributes that every matrix in my code will have, and I also have a third specialty matrix type that uses less storage (differently than `SymmetricMatrix`.  I don't want to have to copy and paste code for each matrix type.

Comment: @Eugene I don't know of any matrix libraries that use less memory for symmetric matrices than regular matrices.  If you know one, please let me know.

Comment: @MountainDrew -- templates provide compile-time polymorphism. Two templates have the same interface if you write them that way. That's how all the standard containers work, for example; their interfaces aren't actually identical, but they provide common functionality.

Comment: @PeteBecker but `Matrix` and `SymmetricMatrix` do have identical interfaces.  The only thing that is different is how they store their contents. (A symmetric matrix can take advantage of the fact that S(row,col) = S(col,row) to cut down on memory usage.  Everything else is the same.)

Comment: Everything actually works fine if I just have `SymmetricMatrix` inherit from `Matrix`.  The only problem is that `SymmetricMatrix` ends up taking up more memory since it has its own array of matrix elements and also uses space for the overridden array of matrix elements from `Matrix` (another thing about C++ that I don't understand)

Comment: I use an old Matrix library Newmat11. It does use less memory for SymmetricMatrix than for Matrix, but it uses dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `multiply` can be a template that takes two (possibly different) argument types, provided they support the appropriate interface. Like this:

```
template <unsigned ROWS, unsigned COLS>
struct Matrix {
    double get_value(int row, int col) const;
    void set_value(int row, int col, double value);
};

template <unsigned ROWS, unsigned COLS>
struct Symmetric_Matrix {
    double get_value(int row, int col) const;
    void set_value(int row, int col, double value);
};

template <unsigned ROWS, unsigned COLS, unsigned INNER,
    template <unsigned, unsigned> class M1,
    template <unsigned, unsigned> class M2>
Matrix<ROWS, COLS> multiply(const M1<ROWS, INNER>& m1,
    const M2<INNER, COLS>& m2) {
    Matrix<ROWS, COLS> result;
    for (unsigned r = 0; r < ROWS; ++r)
        for (unsigned c = 0; c < COLS; ++c) {
            double val = 0.0;
            for (unsigned rc = 0; rc < INNER; ++rc)
                val += m1.get_value(r, rc) * m2.get_value(rc, c);
        result.set_value(r, c, val);
        }
    return result;
}
```

`M1` and `M2` are template template parameters; that is, they're templates that are used as template arguments to `multiply`; the compiler will figure out their types, and the corresponding values of `ROW`, `COL`, and `INNER` when the function is called.

```
int main() {
    Matrix<3, 5> res;

    Matrix<3, 4> x1;
    Matrix<4, 5> x2;
    res = multiply(x1, x2);

    Symmetric_Matrix<3, 4> sx1;
    Symmetric_Matrix<4, 5> sx2;
    res = multiply(sx1, sx2);

    res = multiply(x1, sx2);
    res = multiply(sx1, x2);

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, real code would provide implementations for `get_value` and `set_value`, but the multiply code doesn't care how those are implemented, so having two different types will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

So I removed a lot of noise in your original question by removing specific code relevant to matrices and tried to boil it down to just what was being asked.

What I did here was I stuck with the base class and instead allow the user to specify the return type they want for the `multiply` function.

I haven't heavily tested this but it appears to do what you're after.

To reduce the number of non type template parameters on the `multiply` function I included some getters for the `row`, `col`, and `numel`. You can of course scrap those and go back to how you had it before, but those member functions will allow you to `assert` that the passed in parameters are correct.

All that being said, as @Pete Becker mentioned, you could also accomplish this without inheritance here. Read his comment for further information.

This isn't a complete example but may help you with the final solution.

```
class MatrixBase {
public: 
    virtual double get_value( int row, int column ) const = 0;
    virtual void set_value( int row, int column, double value ) const = 0;
    virtual std::uint32_t get_rows( ) const = 0;
    virtual std::uint32_t get_cols( ) const = 0;
    virtual std::uint32_t get_numel( ) const = 0;
    virtual ~MatrixBase( ) = default;
};

template<std::uint32_t Rows, std::uint32_t Cols, std::uint32_t Numel>
class Matrix : public MatrixBase {
public:
    double get_value( int row, int column ) const override { 
        return 1.0; 
    }

    void set_value( int row, int column, double value ) const override { }

    std::uint32_t get_rows( ) const override {
        return Rows;
    };

    std::uint32_t get_cols( ) const override {
        return Cols;
    }

    std::uint32_t get_numel( ) const override {
        return Numel;
    }

private:
    std::array<double, Numel> values_{ };
};

template<std::uint32_t Rows, std::uint32_t Cols, std::uint32_t Numel>
class MatrixSum : public MatrixBase {
public:
    double get_value( int row, int column ) const override {
        return 1.0;
    }

    void set_value( int row, int column, double value ) const override { }

    std::uint32_t get_rows( ) const override {
        return Rows;
    };

    std::uint32_t get_cols( ) const override {
        return Cols;
    }

    std::uint32_t get_numel( ) const override {
        return Numel;
    }

private:
    std::array<double, Numel> values_{ };
};


template<typename T, std::uint32_t Inner>
static T multiply( const MatrixBase& m1, const MatrixBase& m2 ) {
    static_assert( std::is_base_of_v<MatrixBase, T>, 
        "Return type must derive from MatrixBase" );

    static_assert( std::is_default_constructible_v<T>, 
        "Type must be default constructable" );

    T out{ };

    // Get the values.
    const auto m1_values{ m1.get_value( 1, 0 ) };
    const auto m2_values{ m2.get_value( 1, 0 ) };

    // Set the values on the new matrix.
    out.set_value( 1, 0, m1_values * m2_values );

    return out;
}

int main( ) {
    MatrixSum<10, 10, 10> matrix_sum{ };
    Matrix<10, 10, 10> matrix{ };

    auto m{ multiply<Matrix<10, 10, 10>, 10>( matrix_sum, matrix ) };
    auto ms{ multiply<MatrixSum<10, 10, 10>, 10>( matrix, matrix_sum ) };
}
```

Or, if you're using `C++20` you can just define a `concept` with a `requires` clause where you can specify the interface a passed in type must have. So, using the definitions above that might look like this.

```
template<typename T>
concept Mat = std::is_default_constructible_v<T> && 
requires( T m, int row, int col, double val ) {
    { m.get_rows( ) } -> std::same_as<std::uint32_t>;
    { m.get_cols( ) } -> std::same_as<std::uint32_t>;
    { m.get_numel( ) } -> std::same_as<std::uint32_t>;
    { m.get_value( row, col ) } -> std::same_as<double>;
    m.set_value( row, col, val );
};

template<std::uint32_t Inner, Mat T1, Mat T2, Mat T3>
static T1 multiply( const T2& m1, const T3& m2 ) {
    T1 out{ };

    // Get the values.
    const auto m1_values{ m1.get_value( 1, 0 ) };
    const auto m2_values{ m2.get_value( 1, 0 ) };

    // Set the values on the new matrix.
    out.set_value( 1, 0, m1_values * m2_values );

    return out;
}
```

With this approach you can completely remove the `MatrixBase` `class` if you wanted and just constrain the `multiply` function to types that expose the desired functionality.

Comment: Thank you @WBuck, there are a lot of good ideas in here I can use.  It's not quite the final solution I am looking for (I don't want to have to specify template arguments every time I call `multiply` and other matrix functions since that would require me changing a lot of existing code) but this definitely gets me closer.

Answer (score 0):

@PeteBecker's answer is the best solution to what I asked, but I will also post what I think I'm going to use as another solution here, since it takes advantage of the fact that a multiplication of two symmetric matrices can use fewer operations than a standard matrix multiplication, and I still want to use a base class so I don't have to duplicate code between `Matrix` and `MatrixSym` (they share more member functions than just `get_value` and `set_value`)

```
#include <array> 
#include <iostream> 

template<std::uint8_t ROWS, std::uint8_t COLS, std::uint16_t STORAGE_SIZE>
class MatrixBase {
private:
    virtual std::uint16_t index_from_rc(const std::uint8_t& row, const std::uint8_t& col) const = 0;
    std::array<double, STORAGE_SIZE> values_{ };
public: 
    // get the value at a given row and column
    double get_value(const std::uint8_t& row, const std::uint8_t& col) const
    {
        return this->values_[this->index_from_rc(row,col)];
    }
    // set the value, given the row and column
    void set_value(const std::uint8_t& row, const std::uint8_t& col, double& value)
    {
        this->values_[this->index_from_rc(row,col)] = value;
    }
};

template<std::uint8_t ROWS, std::uint8_t COLS>
class Matrix : public MatrixBase<ROWS, COLS, ROWS*COLS> {
private:
    std::uint16_t index_from_rc(const std::uint8_t& row, const std::uint8_t& col) const {
        return row*COLS + col; 
    }
};

// Symmetric matrix "MatrixSym": must be square as well, so only need to specify ROWS, since ROWS = COLS 
template<std::uint8_t ROWS>
class MatrixSym : public MatrixBase<ROWS, ROWS, ROWS*(ROWS+1)/2> {
private:
    std::uint16_t index_from_rc(const std::uint8_t& row, const std::uint8_t& col) const {
        std::uint8_t z;
        return ( ( z = ( row < col ? col : row ) ) * ( z + 1 ) >> 1 ) + ( col < row ? col : row ) ;
    }
};

// General function to multiply a MatrixBase and MatrixBase and output a Matrix
template<std::uint8_t ROWS, std::uint8_t COLS, std::uint8_t INNER, std::uint16_t STORAGE_SIZE1, std::uint16_t STORAGE_SIZE2>
Matrix<ROWS,COLS> operator*( const MatrixBase<ROWS,INNER,STORAGE_SIZE1>& inMatrix1, const MatrixBase<INNER,COLS,STORAGE_SIZE2>& inMatrix2){
    std::cout << "Multiplying two MatrixBase objects and outputting a Matrix" << std::endl;
    Matrix<ROWS,COLS> outMatrix;
    for (std::uint8_t r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
        for (std::uint8_t c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
            double val = 0.0;
            for (std::uint8_t rc = 0; rc < INNER; rc++) {
                val += inMatrix1.get_value(r,rc)*inMatrix2.get_value(rc,c);
            }
            outMatrix.set_value(r,c,val);
        }
    }
    return outMatrix;
}

// Special case function: multiply a MatrixSym and MatrixSym and output a MatrixSym
template<std::uint8_t ROWS>
MatrixSym<ROWS> operator*( const MatrixSym<ROWS>& inMatrix1, const MatrixSym<ROWS>& inMatrix2){
    std::cout << "Multiplying two MatrixSym objects and outputting a MatrixSym" << std::endl;
    MatrixSym<ROWS> outMatrix;
    for (std::uint8_t r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
        for (std::uint8_t c = r; c < ROWS; c++) { // improve efficiency by starting c at r (instead of 0) for symmetric matrices
            double val = 0.0;
            for (std::uint8_t rc = 0; rc < ROWS; rc++) {
                val += inMatrix1.get_value(r,rc)*inMatrix2.get_value(rc,c);
            }
            outMatrix.set_value(r,c,val);
        }
    }
    return outMatrix;
}

int main( ) {
    MatrixSym<3> S;
    Matrix<3,3> A;

    std::cout << "sizeof(A) = " << sizeof(A) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(S) = " << sizeof(S) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Calculating A*A" << std::endl;
    auto AtimesA = A*A; // auto = Matrix
    std::cout << "Calculating S*A" << std::endl;
    auto StimesA = S*A; // auto = Matrix
    std::cout << "Calculating A*S" << std::endl;
    auto AtimesS = A*S; // auto = Matrix
    std::cout << "Calculating S*S" << std::endl;
    auto StimesS = S*S; // auto = MatrixSym
    std::cout << "Calculating S*S*A" << std::endl;
    auto StimesStimesA = S*S*A; // auto = MatrixSym
}
```

which outputs:

```
sizeof(A) = 80
sizeof(S) = 56
Calculating A*A
Multiplying two MatrixBase objects and outputting a Matrix
Calculating S*A
Multiplying two MatrixBase objects and outputting a Matrix
Calculating A*S
Multiplying two MatrixBase objects and outputting a Matrix
Calculating S*S
Multiplying two MatrixSym objects and outputting a MatrixSym
Calculating S*S*A
Multiplying two MatrixSym objects and outputting a MatrixSym
Multiplying two MatrixBase objects and outputting a Matrix
```